# How to redirect to Etherscan website when transaction completes?

Tags: web3js, blockchain, ether, javascript, kovan

In my project, I am doing a transaction by using

> ethereum.send({ })

method from **web3** in javascript using metamask.  After the transaction completes I want to display the link to the user in label which will redirect to the Etherscan website with the current transaction details such that user can view transaction details on clicking that. Like this link :
https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0x5ffc0cd24cc1bba25df0d971ae4cbabbf0979aa76909272387bda6a0ab96dd64.
Currently I am using **Kovan Testnet Network**. How to get this complete link?

Answer (score 1):

When sending `transaction` you can use events to get the `transaction hash` and using the `transaction hash` can create and `redirect` the user to the `etherscan`.

This example is using the `window` object

```
 myContract.methods.myMethod(123).send({from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe'})
.on('transactionHash', (hash) => {
 // similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/" + transactionHash);

// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/" + transactionHash;
})
```

If using React, Angular or Vue, you can redirect using router

Comment: Yes currently I am doing this only but Is there any way so that we can get the complete link? It will be useful in case we change the network. Otherwise, every time I need to change the code

Comment: There is none currently, but you can write up your own function that can return the `url` based on the network `ID`